# headless with rails selenium-webdriver to take a screen of webpage by linux server

Tags: linux, ruby-on-rails-4, selenium, headless-browser

I use

```
gem 'selenium-webdriver'
```

to take screenshot of web page by my linux server with rails like :

```
def test
  width = 1024
  height = 728
  driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for :firefox
  driver.navigate.to 'http://google.fr'
  driver.execute_script %Q{
   window.resizeTo(#{width}, #{height});
  }
  driver.save_screenshot("#{Rails.root}/screenshot.png")
  driver.quit
end
```

I need to execute this without install browser on my server with no display.

how execute this in headless mod?

Answer (score 3):

You can test it headless on selenium. In order to do so, you will need Xvfb and Firefox. On Ubuntu:

```
sudo apt-get install xvfb
sudo apt-get install firefox
```

Then You will need to run xvfb with some display number (prefere higher numbers to avoid conflicts):

```
sudo Xvfb :99 -ac
```

Export env var DISPLAY with the same number which You have started Xvfb. If You didn't run xvfb in the background, You will need another terminal:

```
export DISPLAY=:99
```

And now try to run Your code

Answer (score -2):

I'd use capybara with WebKit to run headless.

Comment: the answer is absolutely off topic no advice, no instructions